# Application Settings binding to instance specific UserControl

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls, application-settings

I have three controls in my application of type MyUserControl. MyUserControl contains a Label which I want to bind to a string located in the Application Settings. Each of the three instances of MyUserControl has its own string in the Application Settings named Description1, Description2 and Description3 respectively.

The problem is that I cannot set the path of the binding in the UserControl to the name of the string located in the Application Settings because then every instance of MyUserControl would bind to the same string.

I have managed to get something working but as I have learned while working with WPF is that the solution I come up with is never the best way to do things :), so I was wondering if there is a better way to do this? Below is the relevant code I am using now:

MyUserControl.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty DescriptionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Description", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl));

    public string Description { get { return (string)GetValue(DescriptionProperty); } set { SetValue(DescriptionProperty, value); } }
}
```

MyUserControl.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApplication.MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Name="myUserControl">
```

...

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=myUserControl, Path=Description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="0,0,0,6" />
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:MyApplication.Properties"
```

...

```
<local:MyUserControl Description="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=Description1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="myUserControl1" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow, Path=Params}" />
<local:MyUserControl Description="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=Description2, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="myUserControl2" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow, Path=Params}" />
```

Comment: Looks fine to me, but you don't need `TwoWay` binding or an `UpdateSourceTrigger` on a Label since a Label doesn't change the value. You could probably remove those to make your XAML shorter.

Comment: You are right, I will remove them. Thanks.